# PhantomJS WebDriver headless: ".click" Method has no effect

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, click, phantomjs, selenium-grid

I hope somebody can help me with my *phantomJS* problem.
I'm running version 1.9.8 on unix 64bit as a node that registers to a selenium hub running on jenkins. If I navigate to a HTML page with a link (which has no `ID` or `name`, which is why I'm addressing it via `xpath` - Unfortunately I cannot change the html code as it is external input), I'm trying to click it to navigate to the upcoming page. Using *Firefox Driver* this worked without any problems, and if I start a local selenium server (windows, phantomJS v. 1.9.8), it works aswell.

My code:

```
System.out.println("current url before click: " + getDriver().getCurrentUrl());
getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//a")).click();
System.out.println("current url after click: " + getDriver().getCurrentUrl());
```

---

Output on local selenium (windows):

```
current url before click: https://initialpage.html
current url after click: https://www.my-link.com
```

---

Output on remote selenium grid (unix):

```
current url before click: https://initialpage.html
current url after click: https://initialpage.html
```

---

There is no error or similar, it just seems like the driver does stay on the old page. I already tried different `phantomjs.cli.args` while instantiating the WebDriver, adding several `thread.sleep()`'s and replacing `click()` by

```
getDriver().navigate().to(getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//a")).getAttribute("href"));
```

but the output stays the same.

Just in case it matters, here is how I instantiate the webdriver:

```
 driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://servername:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs());
```

I appreciate any help, thanks for the effort guys! If there are any questions left, feel free to ask! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just in case somebody stumbles across this thread, I finally managed to figure it out after hours and hours of desperation. The problem was the instantiation of the webdriver which lacked an ssl related property. This is how it works for me now:

```
final ArrayList<String> cliArguments = new ArrayList<String>();
cliArguments.add("--ssl-protocol=any");
final DesiredCapabilities dCap = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
dCap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArguments);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://servername:4444/wd/hub"), dCap);
```

Comment: This leads me to believe that you didn't have the same PhantomJS version on the server. Perhaps you had 1.9.7. Note that PhantomJS 1.9.8 installed through npm is actually 1.9.7, because their versioning went off the rails when the SSL protocol issue appeared.

Comment: Hi, I downloaded 1.9.8 from phantomjs.org, untar'd it on my unix machine and set it as phantomjs.binary.path variable to my selenium node (that registers to a hub). What was different tho, is the selenium server version (but that should not affect the phantomjs version that i pass, should it?)

Comment: Hm, the selenium-server version shouldn't have an effect here.